# Jquery onchange update another dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used two dropdown list

I wish that when the user selects 2 in the first list then the following script is executed:

```
  $('select[name="service"]').change(function(){
    $('#modal-hs').show();
  });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gerwaf8/1/)

I tried to execute several things like:

```
$('select[name="service"]').on('change', function (e){...});
```

or

```
$('select[name="service"]').trigger('change', function() { .. });
```

But it is not working.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Can you be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `$('select[name="reason"]').change` handler like this:

```
// ...
if ($(this).val() == "2") {
      $('#add-status').show();
      $('select[name="service"]>option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
      $('select[name="service"]').prop('disabled', true);
      // Trigger the change event
      $('select[name="service"]').trigger('change');
}
```

Here is updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6gerwaf8/2/

The reason why you have to trigger the `change` event manually is because the `change` event requires an actual browser event initiated by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
if ($(this).val() == "2") {
      $('#add-status').show();
      $('select[name="service"]>option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
      $('select[name="service"]').prop('disabled', true);
      $('select[name="service"]').trigger("change");
    }
```